# Mapbox open source and using key?

Tags: javascript, maps, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have gone through MapBox's open source libraries and primarily interested in using [mapbox-gl-js](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js)

But, I am unable to understand why I need to use mapbox's key with open source library. Is it built to use the key otherwise I cannot?
I want to use this library as a prototype in my company and want to make sure what the implications are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The access token is only needed if you are using tiles, styles, fonts, sprites, etc hosted by Mapbox servers.

If you host your own vector tiles or use those hosted by another service, the access token is not needed.

- https://www.mapbox.com/help/define-access-token
- https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/third-party